# How long should automatic doors delay closing?

Tags: accessibility, physical

Automatic doors have a sensor that detect whether people are present, and when there are none, and after a delay, the doors close.

How long should that closing delay be?

- Does it depend on factors like type of traffic, and if so what?
- Are there any guidelines or safety regulations for it?
- Does it depend on the properties of the door, like closing speed and sensor range?

To be specific, I'm interested in automatic doors that serve public foot traffic, for building entrances, of the see-through kind that do not cause significant injury when closed.

Comment: @Gustav raised an interesting question in a comment: Is the door facing a sidewalk? If so, are sensors capable of distinguishing between people walking by and people entering (by their trajectory)? "Close Door" even if somebody is nearby because the trajectory indicates he' not entering?

Comment: They should stay open long enough for a person to pass through.

Comment: The real problem is making them open before I almost walk into them (looking at you Walmart)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As per [the ADA guidelines,the recommendations for doors are](https://adata.org/factsheet/opening-doors-everyone)

> Doors that snap closed quickly make it difficult for users,
>   particularly those with disabilities, to get through safely. Doors
>   with closers should take at least 5 seconds to move from the open
>   position at 90 degrees to 12 degrees from the latch. Doors with spring
>   hinges should take at least 1.5 seconds to close from the open
>   position of 70 degrees. Closing times for automatic doors vary
>   depending on the type of door (swinging, sliding or folding) as well
>   as the dimensions and weight of the door. American National Standards
>   Institute (ANSI) A156.10 covers the requirements for “full power”
>   automatic doors; ANSI A156.19 addresses “low energy” or “power
>   assisted” doors.

With regards to the closing times,Here is what I found on the time intervals for how long a door should be open (folding or sliding door) [as per the  A156.10 document](https://law.resource.org/pub/us/cfr/ibr/003/bhma.a156.10.1999.pdf)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I guess @Mervin Johnsingh has already answered it with the facts and figures.

I just wanted to highlight my experience and my thoughts automatic doors(Sliding).

If there is a automatic sliding door, one expects it to open at a safe distance without decreasing the speed of walking(with doubts in mind if its going to open or not)

Similarly, when one enters the door, it should close when the person has crossed a mark or some distance. Instead of time, I feel it should be function of distance.

[image: X is safe distance]

As shown above, at X distance remaining from the door, it should open and wait till the person traveled same distance other side of door before closing.

For example, if the distance remaining is Y and door is still closed, one starts doubting if its working properly or not and raises doubts.

My take, it should depend on Distance of people from door.

Comment: but what happens if he doesn't go straight forward?

Comment: He is a cranky person I see.